# No Export Tracking information option in ET Members GUI, how to export tracking data?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I want to export email tracking data, found this guide ( http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/data_extract_activity/how_to_create_a_data_extract_activity/ ). But I couldn't find any 'Data Extract' option under 'Activities' tab as pointed out in the guide above. Please see the screenshot attached.

Is there ay other way to get this tracking data?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsJsl.jpg

PS: I do not want to use APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for then is a Report.  You can find the documentation on reports [here](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/tracking/reports/).

If you don't find the report you are wanting, and would like to use data extracts, contact your Account Rep, and they will be happy to get that turned on for you.

Comment: I do not need a report, I actually need the tracking data about sends, bounces etc from Application DB and create my own customized reports. How may I contact an Account representative?? Do we have an email distribution list?

Comment: You should have a direct contact at ExactTarget who manages your account - I'm not sure who that would be specifically, I believe the title is Relationship Manager.  If you don't know who this is, contact Global Support, they should get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Kelly. I just got hold of my account representative and he got the 'Data Extract' option turned on. So thanks for pointing in the right direction. I tried following the guide I mentioned above, but it seems like there are no "Extract Types" available for me to select. Do I have to create one or get something turned on ?? ScreenShot: http://imgur.com/6z5gEB7

Comment: <sigh>  Those will need turned on as well. Just let them know they aren't showing up. If you run into any specific issues with the extracts itself, we can start a new question.